# recursive sql function needed

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a simple self referencing table as depicted here:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Project](
    [ProjectId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProjectName] [nvarchar](255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [ParentProjectId] [int] NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Project] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProjectId] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Project]  WITH CHECK
ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Project_Project] FOREIGN KEY([ParentProjectId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Project] ([ProjectId])
```

I am trying to get a stored proc that will output the records in a tree view type way with a generated field that will index the level of each of the items like a table of contents like so:

```
1.0       parent
1.1       1st child
1.2       2nd child
1.2.1    1st grandchild of 2nd child
```

i have this proc that returns lvl but that's a flat representation and i want a field such as the numbers displayed above (1.1.1, 1.2 and so on)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[rpt_ExpandProjectList_stefano]    
( @ProjectId int = null)    
AS    
BEGIN    
WITH ProjectList(ProjectId, ParentProjectId, ProjectName,
                 ParentPath, Fullpath, Level)  
AS  
(  
-- Anchor member definition  
    SELECT p.ProjectId, p.ParentProjectId, p.ProjectName, CONVERT(nvarchar(1000), ''), CONVERT(nvarchar(1000), p.ProjectName) AS FullPath, 0 AS Level  
    FROM Project AS p     
    WHERE p.ProjectId = @ProjectId  
    UNION ALL  
-- Recursive member definition  
    SELECT p.ProjectId, p.ParentProjectId, p.ProjectName, CONVERT(nvarchar(1000), d.FullPath), CONVERT(nvarchar(1000), d.FullPath + '|' + p.ProjectName) as FullPath, Level + 1  
    FROM Project AS p  
    INNER JOIN ProjectList AS d  
       ON p.ParentProjectId = d.ProjectId  
)  
-- Statement that executes the CTE  
SELECT pl.ProjectId, pl.ParentProjectId, pl.ProjectName, pl.ParentPath, pl.FullPath, pl.Level  
FROM ProjectList pl  
ORDER BY pl.FullPath  
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version that may help

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[rpt_ExpandProjectList_stefano]    
( @ProjectId int = null)    
AS    
BEGIN    

WITH ProjectNode (ProjectId, ParentProjectId, ProjectName, ProjectNode)
AS
(
-- Derive project node ID
    SELECT ProjectId, ParentProjectId, ProjectName,
        CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ParentProjectId ORDER BY ProjectId) AS VARCHAR) AS ProjectNode
    FROM Project
),

    ProjectList(ProjectId, ParentProjectId, ProjectName,
                 ParentPath, Fullpath, Level, FullNodePath)  
AS  
(
-- Anchor member definition  
    SELECT p.ProjectId, p.ParentProjectId, p.ProjectName, CONVERT(nvarchar(1000), ''), 
        CONVERT(nvarchar(1000), p.ProjectName) AS FullPath, 0 AS Level,
        CONVERT(nvarchar(1000), p.ProjectNode) AS FullNodePath
    FROM ProjectNode AS p     
    WHERE p.ProjectId = @ProjectId  
    UNION ALL  
-- Recursive member definition  
    SELECT p.ProjectId, p.ParentProjectId, p.ProjectName, CONVERT(nvarchar(1000), d.FullPath), 
        CONVERT(nvarchar(1000), d.FullPath + '|' + p.ProjectName) as FullPath, Level + 1,
        CONVERT(nvarchar(1000), d.FullNodePath + '.' + p.ProjectNode) AS FullNodePath       
    FROM ProjectNode AS p  
    INNER JOIN ProjectList AS d  
       ON p.ParentProjectId = d.ProjectId  
)

-- Statement that executes the CTE  
SELECT pl.ProjectId, pl.ParentProjectId, pl.ProjectName, pl.ParentPath, pl.FullPath, pl.Level, pl.FullNodePath
FROM ProjectList pl  
ORDER BY pl.FullPath  
END
```

You'll find an additional CTE (before your original CTE) that derives a row number value for each group of ParentProjectId values.  The row number is used as the numeric ID element.

Comment: as this table has a FK constraint on projectID and ParentProjectID when we run the SP, it is giving "The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted" error!

Comment: @Aamod Thakur - What is the maximum level value in your data?  Are there many children, grandchildren, etc. projects for each top-level project.  Does the original query produce the same error?

Comment: Yes, in my case i have taken projectID=1 and ParentProjectID =1 for the root node.

Comment: I think what you get with a recursive CTE and your values is an infinite loop.  The max recursion 100 setting kills the statement instead of staying in the loop.  For your top-level projects, what are the ParentProjectId values (NULL, indicating "no Parent project", would be the desirable value)?